# appropriate means of sharing a list among servers

Tags: web-crawler, distributed-computing

I have many web crawlers running on different servers.

I would like these crawlers to share the fingerprint of each url they have already crawler.

I can do this by simply having each crawler check for the finderprint in an SQL server.

but - is there a more approprate way? I'm, just looking for inclusion in a set. SQL server seems a bit overkill.

I'm running on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There are other data stores, [redis](http://redis.io/) is very common, but if you are running on Microsoft, you might want to look into [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/). Both are basically key/value stores with some additional features, but you don’t need to use those.